# Why do I get this message whenever I try to run my simulation. Simulation time limit reached -- at t=10000, events #1

Tags: omnet++

Whenever I try to run my simulation in omnet++ I get the message Simulation time limit reached -- at t=10000, events #1. I can't tell what is stoping my program from properly running.

Here is my NED code:

```
simple rdr
{
    gates:
        input in[];
        output out[];
}

//

network radr
{
    @display("bgb=356,232");
    submodules:
        rdrchk1: rdr {
            @display("p=49,41");
        }
        rdrfail1: rdr {
            @display("p=207,146");
        }
        rdrsucess1: rdr {
            @display("p=207,48");
        }
    connections:
        rdrchk1.out++ --> {   } --> rdrfail1.in++;
        
        rdrchk1.out++ --> {   } --> rdrsucess1.in++;
        
        
}
```

Here is my c++ code.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <omnetpp.h>

using namespace omnetpp;


class rdr : public cSimpleModule
{
  protected:
    // The following redefined virtual function holds the algorithm.
    virtual void initialize() override;
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;


};

// The module class needs to be registered with OMNeT++
Define_Module(rdr);

void rdr::initialize()
{
    int v1 = rand() % 100;
        int v2 = rand() % 100;
        int v3 = rand() % 100;
    if (strcmp("rdrchk1.out", getName()) == 0) {
        cMessage *msg = new cMessage("objectcheck");

     if (v1<78|| v2 < 82 || v3 <69){
                 send(msg, "rdrsucess1.in");

     }
     else{
         send(msg, "rdrfail1");

     }
    }

}

void rdr::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{

    send(msg, "out");
}
```

Here is my ini code:

```
[General]
network = radr
cpu-time-limit = 1000s
real-time-limit = 1000s
sim-time-limit = 1000s
simtime-resolution = ps
```

My program is supposed to generate a msg at rdrchk1 and then send it out to either rdrfail1 or rdrsucess1. If anyone can show me what I am missing that would be great. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you show `omnetpp.ini`?

Comment: @JerzyD. I added the ini file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `.out` from `"rdrchk1.out"` allows the simulation to progress pass if `(strcmp("rdrchk1.out", getName()) == 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is stopping it: `sim-time-limit = 1000s`

as a side note, remove also `cpu-time-limit` and `real-time-limt`.

Comment: When I remove the time limits I instead get the message No more events, simulation completed --at t=0s, event #0